# Cancel pending rest call in ngrx effect

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects, angular-httpclient

whithin my Angular app I have a upload page. 
The upload is handled by a service and triggered by an NGRX effect.

```
// service 
public upload(file: File): any {
  const formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file, file.name);

  // create a http-post request and pass the form
  // tell it to report the upload progress
  const request = new HttpRequest('POST', url, formData, {
    reportProgress: true
  });

  return this.httpClient.request(request);}


// Effect
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
  uploadFile = this.actions
    .ofType(ActionTypes.UploadFile)
    .map(toPayload)
    .switchMap(file =>
      this.service.upload(file).map(event => {
        if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
          // calculate the progress percentage
          const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
          this.store.dispatch(new UpdateUploadProgressAction(percentDone));
        } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          if (event.status >= 400) {
            console.error(event);
            this.store.dispatch(new UploadFileFailureAction(event));
          } else {
            this.store.dispatch(new UploadFileSuccessAction(event.body));
          }
        }
      })
    );
```

Since the upload can take some time (at least the validation of the file), I want to provide the user the **opportunity to abort the pending request.**

Usually you can use the unsubscribe method like this:

```
cons sub = this.service.upload(file);
... 
sub.unsubscribe();
```

But I don't have a clue how to do this inside an effect.
Any suggestions or best practices ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Solved my issue (Y)

the operator takeUntil() does the job 

this.service.upload()
.takeUntil(someAction)
.map(..)

Comment: Can you please write answer?

Comment: The answer is in the comment. TakeUntil() will unsubscribe automatically.